# Generic parameter of array type

Tags: generics, rust, types, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I'd like to create a struct that is type-indexed (or, I guess as the Rust programmers would say, has a generic parameter of some array type). Something like this:

```
struct Frame<const N: u8, const NS: [u8; N]> {
    frame_num: u8,
    subframe_num: u8,
}

impl<const N: u8, const NS: [u8; N]> Frame<N, NS> {
    pub fn start() -> Self {
        Frame{ frame_num: 0, subframe_num: 0, }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.subframe_num += 1;
        if self.subframe_num == NS[self.frame_num as usize] {
            self.subframe_num = 0;
            self.frame_num += 1;
            if self.frame_num == N {
                self.frame_num = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

...

let foo: Frame<2, [5, 8]> = Frame::start();
```

This doesn't typecheck because, quoting `rustc`:

```
error[E0770]: the type of const parameters must not depend on other generic parameters
  --> src/main.rs:32:42
   |
32 | struct Frame<const N: u8, const NS: [u8; N]> {
   |                                          ^ the type must not depend on the parameter `N`
```

I tried using [`const_generic_wrap`](https://docs.rs/const-generic-wrap/0.3.0/const_generic_wrap/index.html) which seems to be aimed at exactly this use case. The extra noise it introduces, while not ideal, is not too bad:

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct Frame<const N: u8, NS> where NS: ConstWrap<BaseType = [u8; N as usize]> {
    frame_num: u8,
    subframe_num: u8,
    phantom: PhantomData<NS>,
}

impl<const N: u8, NS> Frame<N, NS> where NS: ConstWrap<BaseType = [u8; N as usize]> {
    pub fn start() -> Self {
        Frame{ frame_num: 0, subframe_num: 0, phantom: PhantomData, }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.subframe_num += 1;
        if self.subframe_num == NS::VALUE[self.frame_num as usize] {
            self.subframe_num = 0;
            self.frame_num += 1;
            if self.frame_num == N {
                self.frame_num = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get into trouble when trying to instantiate this type. I can't write `Frame<2, [5, 8]>` as the type, because my type parameter is of type `ConstWrap...`. It seems `const_generic_wrap` exposes no way of producing a `ConstWrap` value that is not a simple type like `u32` etc.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I'm willing to use any nightly/unstable features.

Comment: Why can't you just take `&[u8]` as an argument? Whatever's going on here with `NS` is really unusual.

Comment: I don't think you can (or should?) pass in constants like `NS` to the type itself, you really should be thinking in terms of data in a struct, even if it's `Rc` or `Arc` to be shared.

Comment: @tadman: I don't want to store the list of frame lengths in memory at runtime.

Comment: They're going to be stored *somewhere*. You can pass in a slice to a `const` after all. I'm also not sure the overhead of a single reference is worth all this fuss.

Comment: @tadman suppose I have many `Frame`s over the same array, then I save on all those references. .y target platform is quite memory constrained (100s of byes or maybe even a whole 1k)

Comment: If you're that strapped for memory you probably want to use a global. The way you're declaring these now, you'll get a separate instance of the array unless you convert that to a reference, in which case I'm not sure you're winning anything in the memory department.

Comment: If you have more than one of these, a `u8` index to a global const array of arrays could be what you need. This is presuming you're not paying for code/data size in the same way as you are for runtime memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to cobble together something via a type-level length-indexed list:

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
use const_generic_wrap::*;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait TList<T, const N: usize> {
    const VALUE: [T; N];
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Nil<T> {
    phantom: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T> TList<T, 0> for Nil<T> {
    const VALUE: [T; 0] = [];
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cons<T: Sized, const N: usize, X, Tail> where X: ConstWrap<BaseType = T>{
    head: PhantomData<X>,
    tail: PhantomData<Tail>,
}

const fn cons_array<T: Copy, const N: usize>(x: T, tail: [T; N]) -> [T; N+1] {
    let mut res = [x; N+1];

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < N {
        res[i+1] = tail[i];
        i += 1;
    }

    res
}

impl<T: Copy, const N: usize, X: ConstWrap<BaseType = T>, Tail: TList<T, N>> TList<T, {N+1}> for Cons<T, N, X, Tail> {
    const VALUE: [T; N + 1] = cons_array(X::VALUE, Tail::VALUE);
}
```

With this, we can define `Frame` in  a straightforward way:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Frame<const N: u8, NS> where NS: TList<u8, {N as usize}> {
    frame_num: u8,
    subframe_num: u8,
    phantom: PhantomData<NS>,
}

impl<const N: u8, NS> Frame<N, NS> where NS: TList<u8, {N as usize}> {
    pub fn start() -> Self {
        Frame{ frame_num: 0, subframe_num: 0, phantom: PhantomData, }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.subframe_num += 1;
        if self.subframe_num == NS::VALUE[self.frame_num as usize] {
            self.subframe_num = 0;
            self.frame_num += 1;
            if self.frame_num == N {
                self.frame_num = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of using it; it's screaming for a macro to make the syntax nicer, but at least it works as a proof of concept:

```
pub fn main() {
    let mut foo: Frame<2, Cons<u8, 1, WrapU8<8>, Cons<u8, 0, WrapU8<3>, Nil<u8>>>> = Frame::start();
    for _ in 0..20 {
        println!("{foo:?}");
        foo.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about how it works for your use-case, but be aware that this is a memory monster compared to what @tadman has proposed. It's not because something is passed as a `const` generic that it doesn't exist. It *just* means that it is computed at compile-time. This means that 1) unless Rust optimizes these away, if you have an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, there exist somewhere `[]`, `[1]`, `[1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 3]` and 2) for each instance of a `Frame`, all that data is duplicated.

Comment: @jthulhu not sure what you mean -- `std::mem::size_of::<Frame<2, Cons<u8, 1, WrapU8<8>, Cons<u8, 0, WrapU8<3>, Nil<u8>>>>>()` is 2, as I expected.

Comment: Yes, but you are overlooking everything that is not part of a single `Frame`, but still has to exist to build `Frame`. `size_of::<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>()` may very well be `5`, but if to build that array you also built `[]`, `[1]`, `[1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, and `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the total memory usage is `15`, not `5`. Besides, you see that `size_of::<Frame<...>>()` is the size of the array, which means if you build two `Frame`s, you're going to have twice the size of the array, whereas if you put a reference to a `const` array, the size of each `Frame` would be `1`.

Comment: With your method, the total memory usage is `k·n·(n+1)/2`, where `k` is the number of instances of `Frame`, and `n` the size of the array. With @tadman's method, the total memory usage is `k+n`.

Comment: @jthulhu How so? Those are all `const` and will be evaluated at compile time ... So I'd actually argue that this method is quite neat.

Comment: @jthulhu *"unless rust optimizes it away"* - Why shouldn't it? All const values get removed that don't get used, and the only `::VALUE` that actually gets used at runtime is the final one. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You won't save any memory doing that. The data `NS` has to come from **somewhere**, and by storing it in a generic parameter, you basically generate an entire copy of the function bytecode for every value, which is very memory inefficient.

If you desperately want to store it in the data segment instead of the runtime memory, you can use `&'static [u8]`. That way you can at least re-use the function itself and only the differing `NS` has to be stored somewhere.

Like this:

```rust
struct Frame {
    frame_lengths: &'static [u8],
    frame_num: u8,
    subframe_num: u8,
}

impl Frame {
    pub fn start(frame_lengths: &'static [u8]) -> Self {
        Frame {
            frame_num: 0,
            subframe_num: 0,
            frame_lengths,
        }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.subframe_num += 1;
        if self.subframe_num == self.frame_lengths[self.frame_num as usize] {
            self.subframe_num = 0;
            self.frame_num += 1;
            if usize::from(self.frame_num) == self.frame_lengths.len() {
                self.frame_num = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Frame = Frame::start(&[1, 2, 3] /* stored in the data segment */);
}
```

Note that using `size_of` as your benchmark here is deceiving, because it doesn't measure the size of the generated code, which also has to be stored somewhere.

---

It **is** possible to pass said `&'static [u8]` reference as a const generic. **However**, at the time of writing, this feature is **highly unstable**.

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![feature(adt_const_params)]

struct Frame<const NS: &'static [u8]> {
    frame_num: u8,
    subframe_num: u8,
}

impl<const NS: &'static [u8]> Frame<NS> {
    pub fn start() -> Self {
        Frame {
            frame_num: 0,
            subframe_num: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.subframe_num += 1;
        if self.subframe_num == NS[self.frame_num as usize] {
            self.subframe_num = 0;
            self.frame_num += 1;
            if usize::from(self.frame_num) == NS.len() {
                self.frame_num = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

const A: &'static [u8] = &[1, 2, 3];

fn main() {
    let foo = Frame::<A>::start();
    println!("Size: {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&foo));
}
```

```
Size: 2
```